# Decrypting files given a sample encrypted file and original

Tags: decryption, ransomware

One of my friends was hacked, all of his disk was encrypted.
The hackers are requesting money, that obviously we don't want to pay.

I am wondering if it's possible to decrypt everything, given that I have some original backed up files (plaintext) and their encrypted versions.

Is there a way to do it without too much complexity? Or if anyone can help me with this? I can provide both set of encrypted and decrypted files.

Comment: No, you can't find the decyption key simply by comparing the 2 versions of the files. At least, not without extreme levels of expertise and a super computer. However, check out https://www.nomoreransom.org/en/index.html to see if the key is already known.

Comment: What you are describing is known as a 'known plaintext attack'.  Modern encryption algorithms (such as those used in ransomware) are designed to be resistant to this type of attack.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Having a sample of the plaintext allows performing a *known-plaintext attack* against the underlying cipher. Unfortunately for ransomware victims, the ciphers typically used by attackers, such as AES, are [not vulnerable](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1512/54184) to known-plaintext attacks in any way that matters. If you cannot obtain the key, you're out of luck. You can only use this as a learning experience and keep more backups.

A known-plaintext attack involves an attacker (in this case, you) being given input/output pairs for an unknown key but being unable to feed arbitrary inputs (or outputs) into the cipher. This kind of attack is useful for performing [linear cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_cryptanalysis), a powerful attack that can break some ciphers. AES is not vulnerable to linear cryptanalysis. Even if you could [adapt inputs arbitrarily](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2846/54184) based on the outputs, you could perform more powerful [differential cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_cryptanalysis), but AES is not vulnerable to that either.